# JAX-RS - @Path Param with Regular expression

Tags: regex, path, jax-rs

I am trying to implement a service using JSX-RS and I have a situation here where in multiple types of requests with varying version numbers should be catered to by a single method.

```
@Path("/url1/url2{version: [[/v][0-9][.][0-9]]*}")
```

this should cater to -

```
/url1/url2
/url1/url2/v1
/url1/url2/v1.2
```

where versions would be 0, 1 and 1.2 respectively.

I have the correct regular expression but the code doesn't seem to accept it
`((/v[0-9])(.[0-9])?)`? I am confused here.

I need to restrict it to only one digit after v and after the decimal point(.) and I need only one occurance of /v*. For example -

`/ur1/url2/v1v1` not allowed

Also I would like to know perfomrance wise, if I have a url with decimal points, is it going to cost me more time to parse it. Do I have to url encode it ? any other suggestions would is appreciated.

The alternative approach is for every version, I have a seperate method with @path param. which is finally the best solution ?

Any suggestion or ideas are greatly welcome !!!

Comment: I have tried this too - /url1/url2{version: [/v{0,1}\\d{0,1}.{0,1}\\d{0,1}]*    it works but I can't restrict the v to 1 and the numbers to a count of 1 again....  and if I remove the *  it will not work without the version param.. the version param is optional here...

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this is the way I do it:

First, the `v` is optional, since you must accept the pattern like `/url1/url2`. So, I would start with:

```
(/v)?
```

The `?` means zero or one time.

Now, if you put a `/v` then you must have a version digit after it (i.e. `/v1`), but that is only if you put the `/v` first, right?

Somewhat like: `(/v\d)?`

There is no need to specify a quantifier for the digit `\d` because by default is one. And the whole group can appear zero or one time thanks to the `?` quantifier.

Now, if you put a version digit, then you can optionally put a second version digit separated by a dot (i.e. `/v1.1`). But this is only valid if you use a version number first, and this group is optional. And if it appears it should only appear once, so we can use the quantifier `?` again for this group.

So, somewhat like this:

```
(/v\d(\.\d)?)?
```

Notice that I used a `\.` to signify that we expect a "dot" here. This is so, because `.` is a predefined regex character class that represents any character, so you must escape it to signify that you expect a `"."`.

So, this works for me for all the test scenarios you provided.

Comment: Thanks Edwin.. I had tried a similar one with but somehow my javax.ws.rs.Path doesn't seem to accept that... it gives the compilation error - Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )

Comment: That is correct, because Java interprets the \ as an escape character. You must use \\ instead (i.e. \\d instead of just \d).